# program keeps executing first if condition

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I'm trying to build a speech recognition app in python,everything works fine but,when I'm executing program the first If condition always executes no  matter what the input is.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import os
from google_speech import Speech
import webbrowser

def speech():
    while True:
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:

                r = sr.Recognizer()
                audio = r.listen(source,timeout=3, phrase_time_limit=3)
                x = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(x)
                if 'hello' or 'Hello' or 'Hi' in x:
                    speech=Speech('Hello,How are you?','en')
                    speech.play()           

                    print('Input: ',x)
                    print('output: Hello,How are you?',)

                elif 'omkara' or 'Omkara' in x:
                    speech=Speech('Playing Omkara song on Youtube','en')
                    speech.play()

                    webbrowser.get('/usr/bin/google-chrome').open('https://youtu.be/NoPAKchuhxE?t=21')

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("No clue what you said, listening again... \n")
            speech()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Executine Voice based commands \n')
    speech()
```

here is my code I have used while to continuously repeat the program but,In first if condition,it should only be executed when there is 'Hello','Hi' in input. First time I say 'Hi',if is valid then,but when the program loops again with another input like 'how are you' it still executes first IF condition,can anyone please help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: `if 'hello'` becomes true instantly. You need to try `if 'hello' in x or 'Hello' in x or 'Hi' in x:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `or` in wrong way there. Try to use this code:

```
if any(check in x for check in ('hello', 'Hello', 'Hi')):
```

Comment: how can I call function back  when exception occurs so that program continues exception. Can you help with that

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because `if 'Hello'` becomes True instantly. Once you have a condition which is true, it will always go to if condition.

You can try to check this using `bool('Hello')`. The solution is to check each string separately.

```
if ('hello' in x) or ('Hello' in x) or ('Hi' in x):
    something
```

Comment: Please go with @Fedor's answer. That is definitely a better way to do it when you have multiple strings.

Comment: I  want to call funtion again when exception occurs but it's not getting called,throws error 'Speech object not callable', how to get it done,can you help

Comment: You have it inside the the `while True` loop. You don't need to call the function again. Just log the error and `pass`. A little advice. Your function name and your variables have the same name. Do not do it. It may cause errors that you cannot foresee.